# Pylons with Elixir

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pylons, python-elixir

I would like to use Pylons with Elixir, however, I am not sure what is the best way to get about doing this. There are several blog posts ([cleverdevil](http://cleverdevil.org/computing/68/), [beachcoder](http://beachcoder.wordpress.com/2007/05/11/using-elixir-with-pylons/), [adam hoscilo](http://hoscilo.pypla.net/2007/03/19/sqlalchemy-elixir-and-pylons-round-one/)) and even an [entire new framework](http://code.google.com/p/tesla-pylons-elixir/) about how to go about doing this; however, I am not certain about the differences between them. Which one is the best to use? Am I going to run into issues using one over the other?

I would prefer not to have to use SQLAlchemy directly because of its verbosity and repetitiveness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graham Higgins [wrote about](http://bel-epa.com/notes/Pylons/Elixir/) a pylon's template for this (do we call them templates ? you know, the packages that get installed depending on what arguments you give to paster create...). I used it and it worked fine.

You may also want to check [this discussion on pylons list](http://groups.google.com/group/pylons-discuss/browse_thread/thread/5be6a0c084a96412?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I'd go with beachcoder's recipe as updated [here](http://pylonshq.com/pasties/271). That said, with the possible exception of Tesla (which I'm not familiar with), they're all lightweight enough that it should be easy to switch between them if you have any kind of trouble; all the hard work is in your model.